# Approaching vertex groups with Python

Tags: python, scripting, objects, vertices

I want to approach two vertex groups belonging to two different objects, making sure that these objects are close together. 
How can I do that scripting?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Given an object `ob`, you can access its mesh at `ob.data`, and its [vertices](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Mesh.html#bpy.types.Mesh.vertices) at `ob.data.vertices`. The vertex groups are defined on the object as well, at `ob.vertex_groups`. Each vertex group has a [`weight()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.VertexGroup.html#bpy.types.VertexGroup.weight) function you can call to get the weight of a vertex.

```
vg0 = ob.vertex_groups[0]
for index, vertex in enumerate(ob.data.vertices):
    try:
        weight = vg0.weight(index)
    except RuntimeError:
        # Raised when the vertex is not part of the group
        weight = 0.0

    print('Vertex #%d at %s has weight %f' % (index, vertex.co, weight))
```

For efficient distance queries (from a point in space to a mesh) you can use the [BVHTree](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.bvhtree.html) module. This may work faster than trying to compute the distance between every point of one mesh to every other point on the other.

Comment: Good catch, I updated the code.

Comment: Lightspeed updating!

Comment: uhmmm, sorry, i want to put very close my objects basing on their 2 vertex groups... why do we consider the weight?

Comment: The code can be used to detect whether a vertex is in the vertex group (use the exception) or you can use the weight itself somehow. The exact use is up to you.